# Angular - comunicacion entre componentes hermanos

Tags: angular, angular5, angular7, angular6

estaba probando el tema de comunicaciones entre componentes dentro de angular, y me preguntaba si existe la comunicacione entre hermanos, es decir, si es entre padre-hijo o al reves se crea lo siguiente:

un emisor :

```
@Output()  emisor = new EventEmitter<string>();
```

pero si quiero comunicar dos componentes que estan al mismo nivel ?...

```
<comp-hijo-1></comp-hijo-1>
<comp-hijo-2></comp-hijo-2>
```

No hay manera de comunicarse ?

He visto que se puede usar servicios, pero no se cual es la mejor forma.
A demas, entre hermanos, siempre tiene q pasar  la info por el padre ????

Comment: Sí, siempre tendrá que pasar por el componente padre que los contenga a los dos. Ese componente es el único que conoce de la existencia (y la referencia) de ambos. El uso de un servicio también podría valer... La mejor forma de hacerlo dependerá del propósito de la comunicación entre esos dos componentes. Si llegaras a explicarla podríamos ayudarte mejor.

Comment: @VRoxa he encontrado una forma.  Voy a publicarlo y a ver si me puedes comentar que tal te parece, gracias

Comment: @VRoxa ya he puesto la respuesta, espero tu opinion, gracias

Answer (score 2):

Respondiendo a tu *approach*.
Usar el `EventEmitter<>` está genial. Es el *standard* para comunicar de un componente a su padre. Lo que no me parece una buena idea es mantener la comunicación padre-hijo directamente des del HTML llamando a un método de la instancia del componente.
Me explico, este tipo de lógica deberías agregarla an los *.ts*, por la mera razón de que es donde deben estar. Deben estar ahí para controlar las cosas bien.

Por ejemplo, poder *debuggar* en algún momento ese *execution flow* y poder ver el estado o valor de un atributo concreto en ese momento des del padre.
O, por ejemplo, resulta que a día de mañana debes hacer que un tercer componente escuche a ese evento, etc.
Hay varias razones y situaciones en las que necesitamos mantener la lógica de la aplicación en el sitio que le corresponde, no por capricho.

---

**Mi propuesta de solución**
Te propongo usar *reactive extensions*, en concreto, para este caso, un `Subject<>`. El `Subject<>`, el cual será propiedad del componente padre va a pasarse a ambos hijos. Uno de ellos emitirá valores mientras el otro escuchará a las emisiones.

Des del componente padre (*.ts) declaramos el `Subject<string>`.

```
@Component({ ... })
export class AppComponent {
  subject = new Subject<string>();
}
```

Y pasamos ese `Subject<>` a ambos hijos (componente padre, *.html*)

```
<text-input [subject]="subject"></text-input>
<info-stack [subject]="subject"></info-stack>
```

Ahora, el componente `info-stack` (o como quieras llamarlo), que va a listar todos esos `text`, se suscribirá a los eventos del `Subject<>`

```
@Component({ ... })
export class InfoStackComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() subject: Subject<string>;
  infos: string[] = [];

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // Se suscribe a los valores que se emiten por el Subject<>
    this.subject.subscribe((text: string) => {
      this.infos = [...this.infos, text];
    });
  }
}
```

Y el componente `text-input` (o como quieras llamarlo), que también recibirá el `Subject<>`, va a usarlo para emitir valores.

```
@Component({ ... })
export class TextInputComponent {
  @Input() subject: Subject<string>;
  text: string;

  constructor() {}

  sendInfo = (): void => {
    // Emite un nuevo valor por el Subject<>
    this.subject.next(this.text);
    this.text = "";
  };
}
```

En el caso de `text-input`, sería totalmente válido un `EventEmitter<string>` y que el padre "rebotara" ese valor por el `Subject<>`.

```
@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  template: `
    <text-input (onInfo)="handleInfo($event)"></text-input>
    <info-stack [subject]="subject"></info-stack> 
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  subject = new Subject<string>();

  handleInfo = (info: string) => {
    this.subject.next(info);
  };
}
```

De este modo, siempre podemos añadir todos los suscriptores que queramos a ese `Subject<>` o hacer que otros componentes puedan emitir, también, eventos por éste. Todo centralizado y manejado por el componente padre.

Te dejo un [*Stackblitz*](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lexy7h) para ver todo el código del ejemplo.

Espero que sirva.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, que diferencia hay entre next y emit para el eventemmiter ?

Comment: La verdad es que ninguna, buena observación. `next` está obsoleto y debería ser `emit`, efectivamente. Puse `next` por un mal *copy/paste*. Voy a actualizar el *Stackblitz*.

Answer (score 0):

He hecho la prueba de la siguiente manera:

### Input component

Este componente es un input text con un boton.

#### .html

```
<div>
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="text" [placeholder]="placeholder">
  <button (click)="sendInfo()"> Enviar info</button>
</div>
```

#### .ts

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, OnInit, Output} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-input',
  templateUrl: './input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input.component.css']
})
export class InputComponent implements OnInit {
  public  text:string;
  public  placeholder:string;

  @Output()
  emisor : EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

  constructor() {
    this.placeholder = 'Escribe algo...';
    this.text = '';
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  sendInfo(){
    console.log('sending info .. => '+this.text);
    this.emisor.emit(this.text);
    this.text = '';
  }

}
```

---

### Input-result component (hijo 2)

Este estara pendiente de recibir un string para guardarlo en su lista.

#### .html

```
<div>
  <h2>Informacion recibida</h2>
  <ul>
    <li  *ngFor="let info of infos">{{info}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

#### .ts

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-input-result',
  templateUrl: './input-result.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input-result.component.css']
})
export class InputResultComponent implements OnInit {

  public infos: string[];

  constructor() {
    this.infos = [];
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }


  addText($event){
    this.infos.push($event);
    console.log('Hijo 2 = Info recibida => '+$event);

  }

}
```

---

## app.component.ts (el padre de ambos hijos)

#### .html

'
Aqui esta la clave, pongo un identificador al hijo que espera la respuesta y le digo al hijo 1 que directamente le pase el evento en una funcion que tiene el hijo 2
'

```
<div>
  <app-input (emisor)="input_result.addText($event)"></app-input>
  <app-input-result #input_result></app-input-result>
</div>
```

#### .ts (tiene mas cosas de lo que necesita pero es que estaba haciendo otras funciones)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {configuracion} from './models/configuracion';
import {InputResultComponent} from './components/input-result/input-result.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers:[InputResultComponent]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'recordando-angular-basico';
  public mostrarJuegos: boolean = true;
  public config;

  public  textInputHijo:string;

  constructor(private inputResult:InputResultComponent ){
    this.config = configuracion;

    this.title = this.config.titulo;
  }


}
```